# Is this product form of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ in the 2-adics correct?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

$$\frac{\sin x}{x} = \prod_{k=0}^\infty \sec(2^kx)$$

I'm unsure, so I'm looking for confirmation, this is my proof for the 2-adics:

Start with the common identity,
$$\sin x  (2 \cos x) = \sin (2x)$$
It telescopes to arbitrary values,

$$\sin x \left(2^n\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \cos(2^k x) \right)= \sin(2^n x)$$
Divide both sides by $2^n$ and then take the limit as $n \to \infty$

$$\sin x \prod_{k=0}^\infty \cos(2^k x) = x$$

Divide to get the form:

$$\frac{\sin x}{x} = \prod_{k=0}^\infty \sec(2^kx)$$

Comment: It's not clear to me how you define $\sin x$ in the 2-adics.

Comment: Sorry I thought it was standard to define it as the power series. $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$

Comment: Maybe I'm not thinking about this the right way, I guess I have no intuition or real reason to do this I just recognized this was something to try out since I was made aware of a similar formula for real numbers $\frac{\sin x}{x} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \cos(\tfrac{x}{2^n})$

Comment: It might be perfectly fine, it's just you have to check that various series converge, various limits exist.

Comment: Check if or where the power series in your "definition" converges, first. Those inverse factorials introduce lots of negative powers of $2$.

Comment: Good point, I didn't really consider the radius of convergence. I believe for sine the radius of convergence is 1/2 so I need to be careful about that.

Comment: Yes $1/2$ is correct : $n!= \prod_p p^{\sum_{k\ge 1} \lfloor n/p^k \rfloor }$ thus $|1/n!|_p=p^{\sum_{k\ge 1} \lfloor n/p^k \rfloor } \approx p^{\sum_{k\ge 1}  n/p^k }=p^{n/(p-1)}$ and the radius of convergence of $\exp(x)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}, \sin(x),\cos(x)$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is $|x|_p < p^{-\frac{1}{p-1}}$. What about the rest ?

Comment: What remains? Seems like everything to me.

Comment: Yeah, but why would you want a sine? Now log, that’s something else…

Comment: Well I figured this was already being used for p-adic L-functions since I know the product form of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ was originally used by Euler to evaluate $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. In my experience, I'm not the first person to come up with this, so thought maybe someone knew some more context to point me in that direction I suppose. Plus, just having a power of 2 in a trig function just seems weird and fun to try out, just idle interest I guess since I don't really see any motivation for any of the p-adic power series other than "we can, so let's".

Comment: If I recall correctly, in Schikhof's "Ultrametric Calculus" he defines $p$-adic sine etc. and plays around with them a bit, but I also recall that when we talked about that in a seminar someone more knowledgeable than me raised the same question as @Lubin: What do you want with that?